# What is the verb for removing spaces from a sentence?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, spacing

What is the verb for removing spaces from a sentence?
Is it *de-space*?

Comment: To the two close voters: This question is clear and concise. Neither is it vague nor overly broad.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a specific word for removing spaces from a sentence. Typically in programming, we would just call it "removing whitespace." I like "de-spacing" though :)

@ajacian81 Isn't trimming specific to removing whitespace from the beginning or end of a string?

Comment: You are correct... it never even occurred to me that the asker wanted to remove ALL white space from a sentence. Who does that?

Comment: Evidently the OP does. I agree it's not a common task, which probably accounts for the lack of a dedicated verb :)

Comment: Yeah... I think I'm out of my league.. let me just go back to my programming sites :)

Answer (score 0):

In computer terms at least, it's called *trimming*.

Comment: Yea, as long as the spaces are at the end.

Comment: If whitespaces inside the string are removed, then it's "[normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimming_%28computer_programming%29#Variants)".

Comment: @DavidSchwartz No. *normalization* is different from this. See the reference you cited.